# one d array into matrix of variable size java

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on this assignment and am stumped at a point and before I can move on I need to solve it.

I am building a program that allows a user to declare a board size, take that board size and populate a square made up of 'O's in that size.  eventually this will be manipulated again to allow the user to input an x and y coordinates and an x will appear at that point.  That is only the first part of the assignment I am just stuck here before I can move on to manipulating the end result I have the input down and I believe I have the array figured out, multiplying the input by itself would guarantee a square,

where I am stuck is having it print out the O's in a square.

example 
user inputs a 5 for board size
system is supposed to print out

```
 OOOOO
 OOOOO
 OOOOO
 OOOOO
 OOOOO
```

I've tried checking my text book and google and such and did not find a way to do it that works.

here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Board {


@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{

    // declares brdsz for board size total, n for input, xco and yco for later date
    int brdsz = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int xco = 0;
    int yco = 0;
    int x = 0;

    System.out.println("The BOARD =version 1.00= (enter -1 to quit)");
    System.out.println("===========================================");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Please enter the side length of the board:");
    n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    brdsz = n * n;
    int[] coodArray = new int[brdsz];
    Arrays.fill(coodArray, 'O');


    System.out.println("Creating " + n + " X " + n + " board..."); 
    System.out.print("Please enter the x-coordinate: ");
    xco = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.print("Please enter the y-coordinate: ");
    yco = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

  }
}
```

the assignment states that this has to replicate a 2d board using a 1d array

as of right now i am trying to just print the basic output and i will be putting in my if statements for the additional conditions at a later time.

here is the sample output

The BOARD =version 1.00= (enter -1 to quit)
========================================
Please enter the side length of the board: 5 [enter]
Creating 5 x 5 board...
Done.
Please enter the x-coordinate: 3 [enter]
Please enter the y-coordinate: 2 [enter]
Marking location (3, 2)...
OOOOO
OOXOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
========================================
Please enter the x-coordinate: 4 [enter]
Please enter the y-coordinate: 1 [enter]
Marking location (4, 1)...
OOOXO
OOXOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
========================================
Please enter the x-coordinate: 3 [enter]
Please enter the y-coordinate: 2 [enter]
Location (3, 2) already marked...
OOOXO
OOXOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
========================================

essentially what i am trying to do is if you input a 5 under side length it would write a 25 length array (5*5) filled with the letter O

example array values 0-4 on line one 5-9 on line two etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 2D array

**For example**, suppose `x = new int[3][4]`, `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and `x[2]` are one-dimensional
arrays and each contains four elements, as shown in the figure `x.length` is `3`, and
`x[0].length`, `x[1].length`, and `x[2].length` are `4`

[image]

How to traverse and intilize the 2D array you can follow following sample as your **blue print**:

[image]

Comment: sorry should have specified even more, part of the assignment is we are not allowed to use 2d arrays

Comment: @dcit17 how come this sounds impossible? can you show us a sample how?

Comment: not overly.  all the assignment sheet says is it wants us to represent a 2d board using a 1d array.  i am trying to think of ways to like print out like for example a 5 by 5 board array numbers 0-4 on line one 5-9 on line two etc.  any ideas?

Comment: post up an sample at least so I can explain base on that ?

Comment: plz edit your post with extra information you added here. For example this one is good? 1 2 3 4 5|
6 7 8 9 10|
11 12 13 14 15|
16 17 18 19 20|
21 22 23 24 25| and | is line breaker

Comment: yes that is what i am kind of trying to do however instead of numbers have them all say the letter O

Comment: i was able to get access to a different computer, would you still like to skype regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

A 2D Array isn't completely necessary (I haven't used them much) but they can be beneficial compared to keeping a 1D array.

For using a 1D array, it would work like this (say the user inputted 5 for the board size). You're going to need to keep up with the size (or width & height)

```
int[] myArray = new int[size * size]; // or if specified, it can be new int[width * height]
```

Then, to find a way to get to the point, is do this:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 4;
int point = myArray[x + y * width];
```

What `myArray[x + y * width]` will do is give you the point in the array at the provided x and y, while the top-left corner is (0, 0):

```
 [ O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O X O ]

 O O O O O
 O O O O O
 O O O O O 
 O O O O O
 O O O X O
```

Then, if `x = 2` & `y = 0` we'll have:

```
 [ O O X O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O ]

 O O X O O
 O O O O O
 O O O O O 
 O O O O O
 O O O O O
```

This works because the array loops according to the width. So if x was 5 and y was 0, it would look like:

```
 [ O O O O O X O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O ]

 O O O O O
 X O O O O
 O O O O O 
 O O O O O
 O O O O O
```